# How to fix the error when configuring saml on Django?

Tags: python, django, saml, saml-2.0

Here are the items I use:

```
python 3.6.8
django 2.1.5
django_saml2_auth
https://github.com/mehcode/python-xmlsec/releases/download/1.3.5/xmlsec-1.3.52.dev0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

all is installed correctly without an issue

When I run the server, I get the error message as follows:

```
saml2.sigver.SigverError: Cannot find ['xmlsec.exe', 'xmlsec1.exe']
```

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution finally. I realized that there is a bug in that library and
I use django_saml library instead.

Following the guidelines of the library we can connect to saml2 using Django 2.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like SAML library requires xmlsec1 executable to be available on the respective machine.

I ran `brew install libxmlsec1` on my mac and this cleared the issue